# Capture a video on Gear VR for my own VR application without publishing application on Play Store

Tags: android, virtual-reality, oculus

I have created a VR application which I am able to use on Samsung Gear VR (Oculus). My application in not published on play store. I just start my applcation on pjone and then Connect my phone to VR set and things are working good. I want to capture a video of my application. I know there is option through "Universal Menu -> Utilities -> capture video" in Gear VR to capture video of applications already installed on the Gear VR but for that I will have to publish my application on Gear VR and then start it from within the GearVR. I can't publish it right now. I read many articles on how some screen capturing applications can capture my video. I tried a few like "AZ screen recorder", "Recordable free" but none of them seem to work.

1. Is there a way to start my own application on Gear VR without first publishing it on play store.
2. Is there a way to use the "Universal Menu -> Utilities -> capture video" option to record video for my own application without starting it from Gear VR.
3. Is there a way to capture the mobile screen using some screen capturing application?